# Browser not loading images In Windows 10/Linux (all os)

Tags: linux, browser, internet

This morning when I opened chrome and started browsing , I noticed that some of the images in websites is not loading .Then I cleared the chrome browsing data and cache but not worked .Then I used Edge instead of chrome the same issue is there . Then I tried in linux the same issue is there. I think there is some issue with the internet settings ,If yes how to solve the issue .Or is it some issue with the router settings

[image]

I have tried a bunch of websites the same issue is there .

steps I have tried : https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmagic/images-not-showing-in-google-chrome-024.html

Comment: Could be images are coming from a third-party site that is blocked by your ISP. It's not the hosts site or firewall blocking the sites, unless you're running Linux in a VM in Windows. Try booting from Linux on USB, e.g., Ubuntu, to confirm that it's the ISP itself blocking the images. Censorship?

Comment: I have tried kali linux live boot but the issue is still there.Not Censorship! because it was  all good yesterday.And I am not running linux on a VM ,linux is running in another machine . Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Try taking a laptop to some free web access location., such as a library or cafe, and look at that site -- if you an see images there and not at home, it might be the ISP.

Comment: I will try and let you know